# Odoo widget js code is working for version 8 but not for version 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

Why the below code is not working for odoo 9 but its working for odoo 8...

```js
openerp.petstore = function(instance, local) {

    instance.web.form.widgets = instance.web.form.widgets.extend(
    {
        'test' : 'instance.web.form.message',
    });

    instance.web.form.message = instance.web.form.FieldChar.extend(
    {
        template: 'test',
        start: function() {
        alert('working');
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error or does it simply not work ?

Comment: are get the any error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
openerp.oepetstore = function(instance, local) {

    local.test = instance.Widget.extend({
        start: function() {
            alert('working');
        },
    });

    instance.web.client_actions.add(
        'petstore.test', 'instance.oepetstore.test');
}
```

Make sure you check the proper version of the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/web.html) because the web client has gone through some major changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Mr. Mani,**

Try this below code,

```
openerp.oepetstore = function(instance, local) {
    # _t and _lt is use for convert text to python and java script.
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    local.HomePage = instance.Widget.extend({
        start: function() {
            alert("Hello Mani...");
            console.log("Hello Mani..");
        },
    });

    instance.web.client_actions.add(
        'petstore.homepage', 'instance.oepetstore.HomePage');
}
```

More information for odoo 9 js read this below best website,
1. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/web.htm
2. http://javascript.qahowto.com/Odoo-9-How-to-override-form-widgets-javascript-openerp-qweb-odoo-9-2100c58

**I hope my answer is helpful. If any query so comment please.**